# Error running python script from windows to linux

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I have a python script that work's perfectly well on a windows OS.

I want to run the same script on a Linux/Ubuntu machine. I changed the parameters that differ, such as... paths/directories, as well as interpreter from python.exe to python3.

Nonetheless, once I run the script I get an error within a function that works just fine on windows. The function is an API call, in essence it calls another python script with pre-defined parameters in json and reads the output from the shell.

```
script_path =  "/home/user/some_path_here/filename"

def ReportsByDate(date = today):
    new_report = subprocess.Popen([
        "python3",
        script_path,
        "reports/list",
        json.dumps({"date": today}),
        "pretty",
    ], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    output = new_report.communicate()[0]
    output = json.loads(output)

    global df
    df = pd.DataFrame(output)
    return(df)
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prod_get_today.py", line 118, in <module>
    ReportsByDate()
  File "prod_get_today.py", line 72, in ReportsByDate
    output = json.loads(output)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

My assumption is that either:

1. The interpreter is not called properly, or
2. The data from the shell should be read differently in linux vs. windows

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: You could also read stderr from "communicate" and print it. Maybe this shows the problem.

Comment: @MichaelButscher OP is not capturing `stderr`, so it can't be read from the communicate pipe.

Comment: @AKX I assumed that the OP is capable of adjusting the code to do that but maybe I should have mentioned more details like that "stderr" argument must be set to "subprocess.PIPE" as well in the "Popen" call to make it work.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Well, without that redirection, stderr will be happily printed to the parent process's stderr anyway, so OP would see the errors anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If you don't need the shell to interpret your command, get rid of it interposing.
- To find a viable `python3`, you could use `shutil.which()` – or `sys.executable` to use the current interpreter. (This could break with e.g. PyInstaller'd EXEs, though.)
- You can use `check_output` instead of manually wrangling a `Popen`. (As it is, you're not seeing whether the command runs successfully, by the way, or closing the `Popen` handle after you're done with it. This will do that.)

```
    output = subprocess.check_output([
        sys.executable,  # this script's interpreter
        script_path,
        "reports/list",
        json.dumps({"date": today}),
        "pretty",
    ])

    output = json.loads(output)
```